# React component not updating on redux state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using react, redux and redux-saga for my project. While fetching a list of users using Redux-saga, I can see that my redux store is getting updated (I can see it from the redux dev tool), But in the component , props are not changing.

I am using a button to get the list of users. And the users are showing up in that component only.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import './App.css';
import { fetchUsers } from "./actions";
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from "reactstrap";

class App extends Component {

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("in render func");
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Redux Saga App</h2>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={6}>

            {this.props.userList?this.props.userList.map((user)=>(
              user.first_name + user.last_name
            )) : ''}
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <button onClick={this.props.getUserList}>Click to get the users</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  console.log("in map statetpprop");
  //console.log(state.userList);
  return {userList:state.userList}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
  return {getUserList :() => {dispatch(fetchUsers())}}
}


App = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default App;
```

**action.js**

```
export function fetchUsers(){
    return {
        type:'FETCH_USERS',

    }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    userList:[]
}
export function userReducer(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_USER':
            return Object.assign(state,{
                user:action.data
            })
        case 'SET_USERS':
            return Object.assign(state, {userList : action.data});
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**saga.js**

```
import {call, put , takeEvery , takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import { setUsers } from "./actions";

export function fetchUsersFunc(userId){

    return axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
}

function* fetchUsers(action){
    const users = yield call(fetchUsersFunc);
    console.log("in fetch users");

    if(users.data.data){
        const userList = users.data.data;
        console.log(userList);
        console.log(userList[0].first_name)
        yield put(setUsers(userList));
    }

}


export function* rootSaga(){
    yield [
        takeLatest('FETCH_USERS',fetchUsers)

    ];
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where is your `setUsers ` action? And in your reducer for your two actions you are changing the state directly. You should always return a new state, you should never update the state directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Object.assign` and you want to make a new copy of the state, you need to make the target object to a new empty object instead of what you are currently doing (it mutates the `state` object, which makes the react unable to re-render). (You can see See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign for more information on `Object.assign`) For example:

```
// copy previous state and new updates to a new empty object  
return Object.assign({}, state, {userList : action.data});
```

I would recommend using the spread operator instead of `Object.assign` though:

```
return {...state, userList : action.data}
```

Comment: but Object,assign also creates a new copy of the object. right?

Comment: actually, no, it copies the new data from sources to the target object, you can see my link in my answer to know more about `Object.assign`

Comment: yes, and I am returning the target object here right? so what went wrong.

Comment: Yes you are returning the target object, but the target object was the old `state` object, so no new object is created

Comment: The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects. This is what the above link is saying. Here the sources are state and the other object. How the target object is state. Could you please clear if I am missing something..

Comment: The first argument of Object.assign() is the target object in which new properties from the sources (second or more arguments passed into Object.assign()) will be merged into it. In this case, the target is `state`. Here is the link of the syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Syntax

Comment: Oh yes. You're right!! Thanks a lot for clearing this up  :)

Answer (score 0):

If state is updated but UI is not, it means something went wrong with `reducer`.

- Checkout `reducer` function carefully.
- If you are using spread operator (`...`) in `reducer` function, make sure the updated data is mentioned explicitly after spread operator.

Example of working reducer function is as below:

```
const UvNumberReducer = (state=initialState, action: UVAction) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UV_NUMBER.LOAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: {
          title: action.data.title,
          subtitle: action.data.subtitle
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```